# Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data

Tags: node.js, typescript, encryption

I'm getting the error below by running the following code.

> Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
> at Decipheriv.final (node:internal/crypto/cipher:196:29)
> at decrypt (/Users/username/dev/playground/node/src/index.ts:14:65)

```ts
import crypto from "crypto";

const key = "13312156329479471107309870982123";

const encrypt = (message: string): string => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, iv);
  return `${cipher.update(message, "utf-8", "hex")}${cipher.final("hex")}`;
};

const decrypt = (message: string): string => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, iv);
  return `${decipher.update(message, "hex", "utf-8")}${decipher.final(
    "utf-8"
  )}`;
};

console.log(decrypt(encrypt("hello")));
```

I've read these posts

- ["Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data" with aes-128-gcm in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266976/unsupported-state-or-unable-to-authenticate-data-with-aes-128-gcm-in-node)
- [Getting error(Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data) in nodejs decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979731/getting-errorerror-unsupported-state-or-unable-to-authenticate-data-in-nodejs)

but I don't think that I'm getting the same error for the same reason. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iv` needed to be common for both cipher and decipher. Should have read the docs

```ts
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

const encrypt = (message: string): string => {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
  return `${cipher.update(message, "utf-8", "hex")}${cipher.final("hex")}`;
};

const decrypt = (message: string): string => {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
  return `${decipher.update(message, "hex", "utf-8")}${decipher.final(
    "utf-8"
  )}`;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using `gcm` as well; I'm not sure it has anything to do with this.

Ultimately, what ended up working for me was `getAuthTag` and `setAuthTag`.

I needed to store mine as a simple string so there's a lot of transitioning to and from `hex`. Since this is going into a database I also have to store the `iv` and now the `authTag`, so I just use `|` to separate the sections.

### Example

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto'

const key = crypto
  .createHash('sha256')
  .update(String(process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY))
  .digest('base64')
  .substring(0, 32)
const cipherAlgorithm = 'aes-256-gcm'

export class PropertiesEncryption {
  static encrypt(str: string): string {
    const initVector = crypto.randomBytes(16)
    const initVectorHex = initVector.toString('hex')
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(cipherAlgorithm, key, initVector)
    const encoded = cipher.update(str, 'utf-8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex')
    const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag().toString('hex')
    const metaAndEncoded = [authTag, initVectorHex, encoded].join('|')

    return metaAndEncoded
  }

  static decrypt(str: string): string {
    const [authTag, initVectorHex, encrypted] = str.split('|')
    const initVector = Buffer.from(initVectorHex, 'hex')
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(cipherAlgorithm, key, initVector)
    decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(authTag, 'hex'))
    const decrypted =
      decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf-8')

    return decrypted
  }
}
```